# Startwith Query (without phrase) in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Following are the sample available data:

- car hire
- car hire for airport
- car hire for airport pick
- car hire airport service
- car service airport
- airport car service
- city car service

Following are the queries that I have tried:

1. **Prefix**, which gives us startwith + phrase only.
   Like If I search for car for airport, we will not be getting results like "car hire for airport service" or car hire for airport pickup.

   Sample Query:

   ```
   "query": {
    "bool": {
     "must": [
       {
         "prefix": {
           "sfield.exact": {
             "value": "car hire"
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   }
2. Tried **match_phrase_prefix**, this also runs similar to prefix

Sample Query:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "sfield": {
              "value": "car hire"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

3. **Combination of Prefix and query_string**,
   I have tried matching first word using prefix and rest of the words using query_string (because sometime I need to match partial matches also, like "car for air*").

Sample Query:

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "prefix": {
                "sfield.exact": {
                  "value": "car "
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "sfield",
                "query": "car hire*",
                "default_operator": "AND"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

**Point 3 works well**, but takes a lot of time while executing for the first time..
Before This query was returning fast result, but now it is responding slowly..
I have used field type as "text" (for query_string searches) and "keyword" (for prefix searches), and my total data size is approximately 60 GB, and my application is created using PHP..

**Please let me know, if there are any way to fetch startwith + all words matched (including partial matches) in lesser time..**

Sample mapping

```
"mappings": {
    "ctype": {
        "_all":       { "enabled": false  },
        "properties": {
            "id": { "type": "long" },
            "cname": { "type": "text" },
            "sfield": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "exact": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample of your date and the query you have tried?

Comment: **Prefix:**
`"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"prefix":{"sfield.exact":{"value":"carhire"}}}]}}`

Comment: **match_phrase_prefix:**
`"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match_phrase_prefix":{"sfield":{"value":"carhire"}}}]}}`

Comment: **Combination of Prefix and query_string:**
`"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"prefix":{"sfield.exact":{"value":"car"}}},{"query_string":{"default_field":"sfield","query":"carhire*","default_operator":"AND"}}]}}`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you just want the `start with` option. So I'll recommend you to use `wildcard`:

```
"query": {
 "bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "wildcard": {
        "sfield.exact": "car hire*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

See [Wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

Comment: Hi,
My concern is getting startwith data in lesser time..
Using wildcard and regular expression takes more time in returning results..

Comment: Than, please clarify your question.